# Sandbox Endpoint creating API Connection Error

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

i have problem when creating a REST API, in endpoint menu.
It give me 'connection error'. as pic attached.https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjVez.png[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjVez.png)
Is there any setting conf that i miss? tq

Comment: No. There are no settings required for this. Could you please check the endpoint is accessible? You can try to ping and check

Comment: Orait done. Firewall problem.. thanks